# Is there a way to import react-bootstrap (Sass) into a css/scss module in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, react-bootstrap

I want the capability to overwrite react-bootstrap (Sass) in a Next.js app. I have this working fine in React apps, but I've been unsuccessful getting it to work in Next.js. I don't want it set globally, set in _app.js, because I need it at the component level. Ideally, I'd like do something like this inside the somename.module.scss file:

`@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';`

And then below that, define my classnames to extend bootstrap classes, like this:

```
.goright {
    @extend .text-right;
}
```

And if this isn't possible, is there another approach to achieve the same outcome with the Next framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I learned more about the purpose of css modules, I realized that I was going about this all wrong. Next supports CSS-in-JS (styled-jsx), which provides most of the kind of customization I need to do.

Comment: Why you say you were wrong? I also want to do something like this but unable to.